# Bootstrap list with badges: put icon right to the badge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter Bootstrap list with badges, and I have also added a delete icon I currently have two problems:

- The badge is automatically situated to the right of the list row, and I want the delete icon to be after and not before the badge (I think it would look better that way). I guess I'm going to need to redefine the badge style, but don't know how to do that.
- The delete icon is not vertically aligned correctly, and I haven't found the way to fix it either.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="mylist" class="list-group">
        <li id="item1" href="#" class="list-group-item">Item1   <span id="badge" class="badge">5</span>
    <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>

        </li>
        <li id="item2" href="#" class="list-group-item">Item2   <span id="badge" class="badge">-10</span>
    <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r77wkzcg/1/) with a small example of my situation.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootstrap elements like `pull-right` have the property as:

```
float : right
```

Under this property, the Document Object Model is reversed. Like:

```
<span>First</span><i>Second</i>
```

would be displayed as: (Note Only Displayed as - DOM is still same.)

```
<i>Second</i><span>First</span>
```

Ans your Solution is JSFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/r77wkzcg/5/ (Updated)

> **In `right` Alignment, the point of connection is `right`. So, the `first element` in the DOM gets the priority to attach to the `right`. Explained here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/rrrr3wq3/1/**

Comment: Good. I would prefer a <ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li></ul> example.

Comment: I was trying to be to the point. He is using `span` and `i` which would make the explanation better.

Comment: Worked perfeclty. For learning purposes: why does float: right inverse the elements order? At first sight it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @RomanRdgz In `right` Alignment, the point of connection is `right`. So, the first element in the DOM gets the priority to attach to the right.  http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/rrrr3wq3/1/

Comment: One last question: in order to vertically align the badge and the icon, you modified the icon size to 18px. Nevertheless, if I make it a little bigger (22px), it does not get aligned again. Any other idea to align badge and icon?

Comment: @RomanRdgz You can change the margin-top to negative. http://jsfiddle.net/r77wkzcg/5/ Better I suggest using relative units like `em` than `px` because they make it dynamic if you are making it responsive. I am just giving an example so I used `px`. Do not get stick to `px`

Comment: I took the em advice. The problem is that I liked how @Bass Jobsen structured his answer, so I edited the HTML. Now, the badge and the icon are not aligned again, since the margin-top attribute does not seem to work. why?

Answer (score 1):

For your items use:

```
    <li id="item1" href="#" class="list-group-item">Item1
    <div class="pull-right">
    <span id="badge" class="badge" style="float:left;">5</span>
    <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"  style="color: red;"></i>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: I like this definition as it is more ordered

Answer (score 0):

Just put the icon after the badge, it depends of html elements order :

```
<li id="item1" href="#" class="list-group-item">
    Item1   
    <span id="badge" class="badge">5</span> <!-- first -->
    <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>  <!-- second -->
</li>
```

And for the vertical centering of the delete icon, you can shift top the icon with a negative margin top (it's not clean but it work, just use a precise selector to avoid overriding all bootstrap elements)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r77wkzcg/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `fa-remove` icon span first..

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul id="mylist" class="list-group">
        <li id="item1" href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>Item1 <span id="badge" class="badge">5</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item2" href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x pull-right" style="color: red;"></i>Item2 <span id="badge" class="badge">-10</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/8wySK2DPfw